# Using condition inside a while loop in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my C# code.

I need validating the user name, I used an if-condition inside the while loop but the thing is that even when the username and password are incorrect, it not executes any statement.

I have tested the query of authentication in database and the output is correct.

I've tried using these three different solutions without success.

Here is my code :

**Solution #1**

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int count = reader.GetInt32(0);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("Welcome!");
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('no data.');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Response.Write("Welcome!");
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('no data.');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution #3**

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[0].ToString()))
        {
            Response.Write("Welcome!");
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('no data.');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? Does it step into the while loop? My guess is there are no rows returned and it steps over it. If not, where does it get to?

Comment: post the command arguments please, i mean the sql query and the sql connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your solutions are valid. You seem to think that your `while` loop is always executed, however this is not the case. When your sql query returns 0 rows you never enter the `while(reader.Read())` loop.

A simple approach, based on your second solution, could be something like the following:

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Write("Welcome!");
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('no data.');", true);
    }
}
```

Note how there is no `while` loop involved.

Comment: Best not to use a reader though but instead limit your query to scalar value via a stored procedure...

Comment: @Nico, yes, but it depends on the use-case. Maybe the validation logic uses email and password to query the database for a display name, real name etc. But if it only checks for the existence of a given username/password combination, then you are right.